# PyInstaller Not Work Python 3.5

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to turn myProgram.py into an executable program. When i run:
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed myProgram.py I have this error:

OSError: Python library not found: .Python, libpython3.5.dylib, Python
This would mean your Python installation doesn't come with proper library files.
This usually happens by missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of Python installation.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Given that this is an ``OSError`` that refers to the Python installation, you should clarify which operating system you're using, and how Python was installed on your system.

Comment: I'm using OS 10.12 and Python 3.5

Comment: Does OS 10.12 come with Python 3.5 pre-installed (10.11 still had 2.7), or did you install that version manually? If so, how did you install Python 3?

Comment: @HishamKaram I try but the code of pyinstallerGUI not run with Python 3.x

Comment: please take alook [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/installation.html#installing-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: @Schmuddi I have installed Python by http://www.python.it/download/, maybe I should rebuild Python with --enable-shared (or, `--enable-framework` on Darwin) as suggest terminal

Comment: @HishamKaram  Yes I have installed pyInstaller with pip, in fact when i run pyInstaller --version, terminal give me 3.2. The issue is that pyInstaller can't see libpython3.5.dylib

Comment: @Cleto remove it using pip then try to install using either `MacPorts` or `Homebrew`.

Comment: @HishamKaram I remove using pip and have installed from the archive follow [link](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/installation.html#installing-in-mac-os-x) but the issue is the same

Comment: @Cleto which command you use to install?

Comment: @Cleto reinstall python

Comment: @HishamKaram How i can reinstall python 3.5  with --enable shared ? If I do this the issue is fix

Comment: @Cleto see this post please may solve your problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15057523/6222397)

Answer (score 0):

Try copletely uninstalling Python and then re-installing it. Programming can be crazy complicated,  but sometimes it's as simple as that.

Comment: I try but pyInstaller not see the library